# jquery getJson method for complex json how to get values using jquery each method

Tags: jquery, json, each

Hi am newbie to `JSON` i dont know how to iterate JSON over $.each function i worked on it but it display always shows value as `undefined` am not sure why it is

here how my json looks saved it as new file `data.json`

```
{ "users":[
            {
                "firstName":"Ray",
                "lastName":"Villalobos",
                "joined": {
                    "month":"January",
                    "day":12,
                    "year":2012
                }
            },
            {
                "firstName":"John",
                "lastName":"Jones",
                "joined": {
                    "month":"April",
                    "day":28,
                    "year":2010
                }
            }
    ]}
```

here i need to iterate name with Joined date in JSon
and i iterate it over Jquery by like this

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.users', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();                                            
        $.getJSON( "js/data.json", function( data ) {
          var items = [];
          $.each( data.users, function( key, val ) {
            console.log(data.users);                           
            items.push( "<li id='" + data.users.firstName + "'><span><p>" + data.users.firstName + "</p></span></li>" );
          });
          $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "users-lists",
            html: items.join( "" )
              }).appendTo( ".nlst" );
       });
    });
});
```

help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jquery code change this line

```
items.push( "<li id='" + data.users.firstName + "'><span><p>" + data.users.firstName + "</p></span></li>" );
```

to

```
items.push( "<li id='" + val.firstName + "'><span><p>" + val.firstName + "</p></span></li>" );
```

jquery doc [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: thanks i got and a small doubt how do i iterate the nested object within the `users` named as `joined`?

Comment: you need to add another $.each loop inside $.each loop. pass the value as parameter for inside $.each loop